# Sequelize orm using Association methods

Tags: ecmascript-6

Sequelize orm using Association methods
I'm working on a API using Node and Sequelize ORM. The database being used is MYSQL. I've used belongsTo() in below code.
Each user have favorite games. Get the favorite games for each user using user_Id.
I got a sequelize result and but excepting another.

```
this.userFavoriteGameModel = require("../entity/favorite_game")(this.database, this.Sequelize);
this.gameModel = require("../entity/game")(this.database, this.Sequelize);

 //Fecth user favorite game list
    favoriteGameList(name, cb) {
        let self = this;
        var user_Id = 5;
        self.userFavoriteGameModel.belongsTo(self.gameModel, {
            as: "game_detail",
            foreignKey: 'game_Id'
        });
        self.userFavoriteGameModel.findAll({
            attributes: [
                'game_Id'
            ],
            where: {
                user_id: user_Id
            },
            include: [{
                model: self.gameModel,
                as: 'game_detail',
                attributes: ["game_Title", "game_Subtitle", "icon", "game_Rating"]
            }],
            group: ['game_Id']
        }).then(function (result) {
            cb(result);
            let obj1 = result;
            let obj2 = Object.assign({}, obj1);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(obj2));
        }, function (err) {
            console.log('An error occurred while creating the table:', err);
            cb(err);
        });
    }
}

[
  {
    "dataObject": [
      {
        "game_Id": 57,
        "game_detail": {
          "game_Title": "battlefield1",
          "game_Subtitle": "Limited edition",
          "icon": "image.png",
          "game_Rating": 2
        }
      },
      {
        "game_Id": 58,
        "game_detail": {
          "game_Title": "battlefield2",
          "game_Subtitle": "Limited edition",
          "icon": "image.png",
          "game_Rating": 1
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]

Excepting Result : 

[
  {
    "dataObject": [
      {
         "game_Id": 57,
          "game_Title": "battlefield1",
          "game_Subtitle": "Limited edition",
          "icon": "image.png",
          "game_Rating": 2
      },
      {
          "game_Id": 58,
          "game_Title": "battlefield2",
          "game_Subtitle": "Limited edition",
          "icon": "image.png",
          "game_Rating": 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

sequelize orm make nested json as result of hasMany belongsTo or other relations if you dont want it as final result you could get the sequelize result then make it manually like what you want follow this:

```
var finalResult={}
for(var key in object){
    if(typeof object['key'] == 'object'){
         var parent=object['key']
         for(var childKey in parent){
                     finalresult['childKey']=parent['childKey']
         }
     }else{
        finalresult['key']=object['key']
     }
 }
```